# Load gz compressed log files from s3 to Elasticsearch via Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I am having gzipped log files in an s3 bucket, and I need to ingest it into elasticsearch. I am currently doing it with logstash s3 input (logstash -> elasticsearch), but I am trying avoid to directly ingest the data with logstash, and instead of that, ingest it with some shipper to kafka, and then to logstash and elasticsearch.

Unfortunately I cant find any solution to do it. Kafka S3 source doesnt accept gzipped files. Filebeat includes SQS (as I understood it).

Are there any suggestions how I could accomplish it?

In the back of my mind, I have the solution to schedule a download and extract python job with, maybe airflow, and to ingest it then with filebeat or directly with python. But it seems a little bit "dirty".

Another question is, is it possible to track the offset if an shipper handles gzipped files? In another words, when a shipper transfers loglines out of an compressed file, will he know, for example, that he came to line 43265 in file.gz after an restart, and start at line 43266?

Comment: Do you need it to run continuously? Or is this only for historical data?

Comment: Filebeat has S3 input source and Kafka output source. Does that help? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-s3.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer it should run continuosly, it should ignore old gzips (eg older than 3 months), and after I restart the service/container it should know where left.

Comment: @JavaTechnical I also saw the Filebeat S3 Input, but it includes SQS. It doesnt sound like a straightforward thing to do....

Comment: I edited the post with one additional question

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a custom script that downloads the files, parses some date information, and tracks offsets (in dynamodb, maybe)... Pure python could work fine, Pyspark if you want to distribute that processing. Maybe Nifi/Streamsets if you're interested a more "framework"/tool approach. I doubt you'll need Filebeat with any of those options

Comment: @OneCricketeer As I thought....I hoped there is some out-of-the-box solution...then I will go along with some python-kung-fu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Kafka isn't part of the solution, then maybe you should use [Amazon Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/) [which streams natively into Elasticsearch](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-kinesis-data-firehose-adds-support-for-streaming-data-delivery-to-amazon-elasticsearch-service-in-amazon-vpc/).  [KD Gregory recommends](https://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=aws.loggingPipeline) using [Kinesis Agents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html) in their instructions.